# Iframe showing error on validation?

Tags: html, css, validation, iframe

In my website(HTML5), i have facebook like option.

But validating through **w3c validation**, its showing error like this:

> The frameborder attribute on the `<iframe>` element is obsolete. Use
>   CSS instead.

If i am using css for `style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:75px; height:27px;`
Then it showing

"The scrolling attribute on the `<iframe>` element is obsolete. Use CSS instead."

```
<div style='float:left; padding:6px 0 0 0px'>
<iframe allowTransparency='true' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:75px; height:27px;'></iframe></div>
</div>
```

If i am removing every inline style and giving in css,then its not showing any error except allowTransparency.

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These attributes should be removed, not the inline style.

1. allowtransparency attribute
2. frameborder attribute
3. Scrolling attribute

Comment: so we should give every thing in styles,then what about allowtransparency attribute.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [W3 HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element) there is no allowTransparency, frameborder or scrolling attribute for the iframe element. So your page will never validate while you try to include any such attributes.

Comment: so client need valid mark up means what we do,we should avoid allowtransparency  right

Comment: @prash The allowtransparency attribute was never really valid, it was just something created by Microsoft without any consultation. You should take a look at the [CSS 3 opacity property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency).